# Troubleshooting a dashing widget

Tags: ruby, dashing

I have created a widget, to display the server load. However, it doesn't display the server load.

dashboard.erb

```
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
  <div data-id="serverload" data-view="Graph" data-title="Server load" data-moreinfo="1 min intervals" ></div>
</li>
```

jobs/serverload.rb

```
points = []
(1..10).each do |i|
  points << { x: i, y: 0 }
end
last_x = points.last[:x]

SCHEDULER.every '1m' do
  points.shift
  last_x += 1
  uptime = %x('uptime').gsub(/.*: /, '\1').gsub(/,/, '\1')
  points << { x: last_x, y: uptime[0..3].to_f }
  send_event('loadavg1min', points: points)
end
```

It simply, displays the following. How can we troubleshoot this particular widget and figure out where it is failing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of the example in the [docs](https://github.com/gottfrois/dashing-rails), try adding the `first_in:` option as well as passing in a hash as the second argument to `send_event`

Try:

```
SCHEDULER.every '1m', first_in: 1.second.since do
  points.shift
  last_x += 1
  uptime = %x('uptime').gsub(/.*: /, '\1').gsub(/,/, '\1')
  points << { x: last_x, y: uptime[0..3].to_f }
  send_event('loadavg1min', { points: points })
end
```

docs:

```
# :first_in sets how long it takes before the job is first run. In this case, 
it is run immediately
Dashing.scheduler.every '1m', first_in: 1.second.since do |job|
  Dashing.send_event('karma', { current: rand(1000) })
end
```

Comment: even after adding first_in I couldn't see any changes in the widget. There is something else that we are missing I guess.